# codeigniter invalid argument supplied for foreach() on join clause

Tags: codeigniter

i try all of away that i know and suggestion on internet.
but all time return false.
please help me...
thanks

my error message is:

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/index.php

Line Number: 10

model.php

```
    public function getBanner()
{
    $this->db->select('album.id, album.cat_id , album.poster, album.slug, album.modify, category.id, category.name, category.slug');
    $this->db->from('album,category');
    $this->db->where('album.cat_id', 'category.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() != 0)
    {
        $result = $query->result_array();

        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

controllers.php

```
$data['banner'] = $this->Fornt_model->getBanner();
```

showbanner.php

```
<section class="banner">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <?php $item = 1; foreach($banner as $latest_poster): $item_class = ($item == 1) ? 'item active' : 'item'; ?>
                        <div class="<?php echo $item_class; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/poster/'.$latest_poster['poster']); ?>" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                            <div class="carousel-caption caption">
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('category/bollywood/'.$latest_poster['slug']); ?>" class="box">
                                    <b class="h3"><?php echo $latest_poster['name']; ?></b>
                                    <small class="p">Exclusive AT*<?php echo substr($latest_poster['modify'], 0, 10); ?></small>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php $item++; endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix" style="padding: 10px 0;"></div>
    <div class="row hidden-xs">
    <?php $itemto = 0; foreach($banner as $latest_poster): $item_class_active = ($itemto == 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>
        <div class="col-sm-2 pointer" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $itemto; ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('images/poster/'.$latest_poster['poster']); ?>" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" /></div>
    <?php $itemto++; endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Error might be in your $banner variable. Whenever, your function will return false, it will show up the error message

Comment: i check data['banner'] variable. it show array but when call on view page than return false

Comment: As mentioned, your error seems to be in index.php and you are running the foreach loop inside showbanner.php. Are you nesting your views?

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with your query.. try

```
 if($query->num_rows() != 0)
        {
            $result = $query->result_array();
            print_r($result);
        }
```

make sure your array data is available..

Answer (score 0):

If there is no rows, front_model->getBanner() will return the result as false. Due to this you are getting an error. Use following code

```
 public function getBanner()
{
    $this->db->select('album.id, album.cat_id , album.poster, album.slug, album.modify, category.id, category.name, category.slug');
    $this->db->from('album,category');
    $this->db->where('album.cat_id', 'category.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();

}
```